# Issue with joomla extensions

Tags: joomla

I'm having issues with a Joomla extension installation.

When I upload them it shows me an error:

> Error Unable to find install package

I searched on google and have increased my upload limit

```
max_upload_size = 256M
```

But still have the same issue,anybody know how to resolve this thank you!

> Error
>   Warning
>   JFTP: :mkdir: Bad response.
>   JFTP: :chmod: Bad response.
>   Component Install: Failed to create folder:
>  /home/keramin1/public_html/components/com_uniterevolution.

Uploaded the files manually via ftp* when i go to discover and it shows the plugin then i press install it loads me this error

> An error has occurred.
>   0 Call to a member function children() on null
>    Return to Control Panel

Comment: Double check your tmp file path in global configurations?

Comment: @Benzema You may receive some/more/better support at [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: Path to Temp Folder : /home/user90/public_html/tmp

Answer (score -1):

Disable FTP in your Joomla configuration settings and then try again. If you still have the problem, then this is likely a permission issue. Make sure that your Joomla instance (web server) is able to write to the tmp folder.